# Find the fixed points and draw the phase space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

> \begin{align}
> x'&=x(2-x-y)  \\
> y'&=y(4x-x^2-3)  
> \end{align}
>
> - a) find the three fixed points and classify them
> - b) sketch the phase portrait

I've found the first two fixed points $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ but I am confused to finding the third. I divided both equations by $x$ and $y$ respectively, and tried solving for $y$, but I am getting $\pm 2i$. I am not sure if this is correct. I understand how to find/classify them using the Jacobian matrix and the determinant/trace, but I do not understand how to draw the phase portrait (does that come from the eigenvalues/eigenvectors at each point?)
$$
J = \pmatrix{ 2-2x-y & -x \\ 
              4y-2xy & 4x-x^2-3}
$$

Answer (score 3):

The singular points are solved as the solution for

$$
y(4x-x^2-3) = 0\\
x(2-x-y)=0
$$

or

$$
(1,1),(2,0),(3,-1),(0,0)
$$

The Jacobian calculated at those points have respective eigenvalues

$$
(\frac{1}{2}(-1-i\sqrt 7),\frac{1}{2}(-1+i\sqrt 7)),(-2,1),(\frac{1}{2}(-3-i\sqrt{15}),\frac{1}{2}(-3+i\sqrt{15})),(-3,2)
$$

so they can be classified as

## sink, saddle, sink, saddle

Attached a plot showing the phase plane and the equilibrium points.

[image]

Comment: wouldn't the eigenvalues for (0,0) be -3 and 2? instead of 3 and 2

Comment: Yes. I had cheated now I hope it is correct.